# Map String to ReadableStream<Uint8Array> in Node

Tags: node.js, typescript, fetch

I need to map from a `string` (or `ArrayBuffer`, if that's easier) to a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`. This is in a NodeJS environment. How is this done? Most digging I've done shows something like:

```
import { Readable } from "stream";

Readable.from("foo");
```

But `Readable.from` returns a `Readable`, and I need a `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`.

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
const stream = ReadableStream.from("foo");
```

Comment: Hey you can use Buffer.from(string[, encoding]). And I think buffer class has also the interface of Uint8Array! Then why do you need Uint8Array specifically if you can use Buffer instead?

Comment: @h-sifat it's because i'm trying to map the string to the whatwg/fetch's response `Body`, which is specifically `ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple if you use `Blob`:

`const readableStream: ReadableStream<Uint8Array> = new Blob(["foo"]).stream();`

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I'm new to node.js I'll try my best to answer the question. But it's not guaranteed to be professional or perfect. Please feel free to edit this question.

[image: Readbale stream example]

To create a readable stream we need to import the Readable Class from the stream module. Then we create a readable stream object. The Readable Class' constructor function requires an object with a "read" method in it.

So whenever another stream will read from our readable stream it will call this read() method. If we have any data available then we need to push it using the "this.push()" method which already provided by the Readable class.

If we don't have any more data then we need to push "null" to signal the "end" of data event.

Now to convert a string to Uint8Array I converted it to a Buffer first then I converted that Buffer to an Uint8Array(as you said you need an Uint8Array). But I'm not sure if it's the efficient or recommend method to do this.

Anyway, here I've taken a string and read it one by one character to simulate the scenario that we are serving a big file. Because the don't want to buffer a big file completely on the memory.

After all of that I piped this readable stream to the process.stdout which is a writable stream. And you can see the output in the next terminal. Why it's converted to string instead of an Uint8Array. Because the process.stdout probably has default encoding "utf8" or it converts the data to string before writing it to the console.

Comment: I appreciate the answer! But unfortunately it isn't sufficient on my end, because `readable` doesn't end up being of type `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`

Comment: @M.Irvin what's the data type then when you read the stream?